# php mysql bar graph doesn't load correctly

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, wordpress, graph

I made a bar graph using `php` and `javascript` and `mysql` actually a dynamic graph.
but it doesn't work correctly it just shows last column record of database.
I want it shows whole requested column records. I don't know what is wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
  <head>
   <title> graph </title>
  </head>
<body>
 <?php
    $psbhostemailaddress = "thepsbhostemailaddress"; //EDIT ME
    $roothostname = "localhost";
    $psbhostusername = "pedy"; //EDIT ME
    $psbhostpassword = "9eKH8qrdm3xYHTJz"; //EDIT ME
    $psbhostdatabasename = "ped"; //EDIT ME
    mysql_connect("".$roothostname."","".$psbhostusername."","".$psbhostpassword."") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("".$psbhostdatabasename."") or die(mysql_error());
    $post_type=array(); $ID=array();
    $table= wp_posts;
    $t=$table;
    if(strlen($table) > 0){
    $exists = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table'") or die(mysql_error());
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($exists);
    if($num_rows>0){
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table");
    if(mysql_num_rows($sql)>0){
    unset($table);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $m=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['post_type']), ENT_QUOTES);
    $a=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['ID']), ENT_QUOTES);
    array_push ($ID, $a);
    array_push ($post_type, $m);
    }
    $biggest=max($ID);

    mysql_close();}}
    else{echo '<script language="javascript">alert("No such table.");window.location="front-page.php";</script>;';}
    }
    ?>

<script language = "javascript">

var m = <?php echo json_encode($post_type); ?>;
var a = <?php echo json_encode($ID); ?>;
var b = <?php echo json_encode($biggest); ?>;
var t = <?php echo json_encode($t); ?>;
var r = b / 100;

if (a.length > 0 && m.length > 0) {
 for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  var divTag = document.createElement("div");
  divTag.id = "a" + i;
  divTag.setAttribute("align", "center");
  divTag.style.marginLeft = (i * 78 + 20) + "px";
  divTag.style.position = "absolute";
  divTag.style.bottom = 100 + "px";
  divTag.style.height = (a[i] / r) + "px";
  divTag.className = "aDiv";
  divTag.innerHTML = a[i];
  document.body.appendChild(divTag);
 }
 for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  var divTag = document.createElement("div");
  divTag.id = "b" + i;
  divTag.setAttribute("align", "center");
  divTag.style.marginLeft = (i * 78 + 20) + "px";
  divTag.style.position = "absolute";
  divTag.style.bottom = 70 + "px";
  divTag.style.height = 30 + "px";
  divTag.className = "bDiv";
  divTag.innerHTML = m[i];
  document.body.appendChild(divTag);
 }

 document.write("<div id='label'><h1>" + t + "</h1></div><div id='myid' style='min-width:" + (a.length * 80) + "px; width:" + (a.length * 80) + "px'> </div>");
} </script>

</body>

</html>
```

and this code is running in my `Wordpress` theme I inserted it into html because it be clear.

[image]

Comment: Please, read this first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: thanks for your reply but i can not find my answer

Comment: There are a lot of problems with Your question and code. The use of mysql_* style functions is one of them. The next thing should be to narrow down Your problem to one language, You have SQL, PHP, HMLT, JavaScript and CSS.